# Gmapping: map doesn't update

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a custom 2 wheel robot using Pololu Motor Shields, with ROS_arduino_bridge to convert odometry ticks into quaternion and publishing to /odom. We also use a Hokuyo Laser Scanner. While running the Gmapping launch file, we are capable of getting the first map. However, it does not update.  We have tried setting small parameters for Angular and Linear update - nothing. When we force gmapping to make a map using TemporalUpdate, it just creates multiple maps and puts one on top of another. On top of everything when we do not use TemporalUpdate, the base scan starts drifting all over the map.

Any suggestions on how to fix these issues:

1. getting rid off drifting
2. updating the map

Our gmapping launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" name="laser_scan">
<param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
<param name="frame_id" value="map"/>
<remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
</node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_base_laser_link" args="0.058 0 0.125 0.0 0.0 3.1416 /base_link /base_scan 100"/>

<node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
<rosparam>
odom_frame: odom
maxUrange: 5.4
maxRange: 5.4
base_frame: base_link
</rosparam>
<remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284133/gmapping:-map-doesn%27t-update/) by [denisolt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33805/denisolt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see several issues with your configuration:

1. the `frame_id` of the `urg_node` should definitely not be `map`. `laser_link` or something would be more suited. Otherwise, the data coming from the laser would always be considered to be sent w.r.t `map`, which makes no sense. This should be the cause for Problem 1.
2. the `static_transform_publisher` needs to go from `base_link` to the `frame_id` you specify above, in my example `laser_link`. This will then provide you with the possibility to transform the laser data from the `laser_link` to `base_link`.
3. The `gmapping` config seems to be correct, assuming you do publish the transform from `odom` to `base_link`.  If this is not published to `tf`, `gmapping` won't update, which could be your Problem 2. You can check with `rosrun tf tf_echo odom base_link` if there is a tf published. If not, you need to create a `tf_broadcaster` from your odometry, see [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) for how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-02**:
I would also add that you have to `remap from="base_scan" to= "scan"`, you have inverted them.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-03-02**:
@Delb You think so? The remapping should be correct, as `gmapping`, by default, has a `scan` topic. So @denisolt is asking `gmapping` to listen to `base_scan`. One could argue that this is unnecessary, as he is doing the same remapping above in the `urg_node`, so you could get rid of both...

**Comment by [denisolt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33805/denisolt/) on 2018-03-02**:
Thanks a ton! @mig everything works!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-05**:
@mig Yes you're right I checked again and `urg_node` is also by default publishing on `scan` so yes the remapping is unnecessary. Thank you for pointing that out !